# Downtime pattern with Azure WebSites and DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, web-hosting, azure

Call me an early adopter, but I recently migrated my web service over from an Azure web-role to a "Reserved instance" on their new web sites service (mainly for git deploy!).

The migration went smoothly, but I'm seeing strange downtime patterns, typically for 5 minutes every 30 minutes (not exact timings but +/- a few minutes). According to Pingdom, the problem is DNS resolution, not the Azure service itself.

I use ZoneEdit for my DNS, have the root domain forwarded to www.
www is a CNAME record which used to be linked to me.cloudapp.net (which worked fine), and is now me.azurewebsites.net

Is this DNS solution a good one? Should I be seeing this downtime? I understand that using A records directly is a bad idea due to reallocation of endpoints etc.

**Thanks!**

Comment: What's your DNS TTL? It should probably be something tiny.

Comment: It was actually the default really large value, 7200 or something. I thought that was simply the CNAME alias that would cache rather than the underlying IP/A Record, I just changed it to 5mins, hopefully this will help. Thanks.